# File format for fast parsing and small size in three.js

Tags: three.js

What is the recommended file format for three.js?
The parameters I'm interested in are:

1. Fast non-blocking parsing.
2. Small file size (can use gzip).
3. Supported features when converting from another format.

I saw examples for:

1. UTF8
2. CTM
3. OBJ
4. JSON
5. Binary JSON

Is there a consensus for a file format?
Are there other relevant formats I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [glTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF) is the best option.
From the glTF [README](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/README.md)

> Applications seeking high-performance, such as games, rarely load interchange or modeling-tool-specific formats directly; instead, they process the model offline as part of a content pipeline to convert the asset to a proprietary format optimized for their runtime application. This has lead to a fragmented market of incompatible proprietary runtime formats and duplicate efforts in content pipeline tools. glTF solves this by providing an extensible open-standard runtime format that can be rendered with minimal processing, along with open-source pipeline tools, that, while not part of the glTF specification, provide the ecosystem of freely-available tools necessary to facilitate adoption of glTF. In particular, COLLADA2GLTF converts COLLADA assets to glTF.

Comment: Can you please modify your answer to explain you reasoning?